# WPF ToolKit DataGrid Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid

I got a DataGrid with 6 column, each column is a RadioButton so that user can select 1 in 6 option. There are about 100 row. I make a custom class with 6 bool datamember, then bind the datagrid with a list of about 100 custom class object. There are 2 problem:

1. The binding time is very slow
2. When I scroll the data grid, sometime the check value of some row disappear.

Are there any known issues with datagrid when bind to a large amount of data like this? And how to improve the performance. I'm using the June Release of WPF Toolkit

Thanks

P/S: You can download my sample app to understand exactly the problem
http://www.mediafire.com/file/jrmft4m4jwm/WpfApplication3.zip

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a VirtualizingStackPanel? This will improve performance for large collection of data for rendering on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, switch to the .NET 4.0 version of DataGrid.

For me it reduced binding time from 80 secs to <0.5secs on 10000 rows, 10 columns.

Also, make sure to use UI Virtualization (turned on by default, but sometimes it gets disabled)
[WPF Toolkit DataGrid scrolling performance problems - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704512/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-scrolling-performance-problems-why/7000666#comment10263994_7000666)