# WPF-datagrid Scrolling bar very slow

Tags: wpf, datagrid, bigdata

I Have in my program datagrid.That datagrid contains about 1000 rows.
When I scrolling the scroll bar it is working very slowly and doesnt give the 
user to see the the data without blasts.
this is the definition of the datagrid:(in xmal)

```
      <DataGrid RowHeight="18" ColumnHeaderHeight="22" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="196,62,8,69" Name="dgItems" HeadersVisibility="All"  Loaded="dgItems_Loaded" Opacity="50" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseRightButtonDown="dgItems_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" AllowDrop="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="dgItems_MouseLeftButtonDown" Drop="dgItems_Drop" DragEnter="dgItems_DragLeave" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="dgItems_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" AlternatingRowBackground="#AC87CEFA" KeyDown="dgItems_KeyDown" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyUI;component/Images/User.png" Stretch="None" TileMode="None" />
        </DataGrid.Background>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="5" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="White">
                        <Button Content="" Name="btnAddit" Visibility="Visible" Height="13" Width="13" Click="btnAddIt_Click" ToolTip="Add to current playlist">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyUI;component/Images/Add.png" />
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"  Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Chapter" Binding="{Binding Chapter}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Genre" Binding="{Binding Genre}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding Rate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Counter" Binding="{Binding Counter}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ReleaseDate" Binding="{Binding ReleaseDate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="InsertDate" Binding="{Binding InsertDate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastRead" Binding="{Binding LastRead}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704512/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-scrolling-performance-problems-why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Toolkit DataGrid scrolling performance problems - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704512/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-scrolling-performance-problems-why)